# Importando imagens da galleria para o app Android

Tags: java, android, imagem, galeria

Estou montando um App no qual quero que ele permita, através de um botão, que eu escolha imagens a partir da galeria e inclua e salve dentro da aplicação. Porém estou com um problema em `IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST` pois o NetBeans diz que não pode encontrar o símbolo. Sou meio leigo no assunto então peço que sejam o mais claro possível na resposta. Obrigado.

```
    public void onImageGalleryClicked(View v) { 

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    String pictureDirectoryPath = pictureDirectory.getPath();
    Uri data = Uri.parse(pictureDirectoryPath); 
    photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*"); 
    starActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST); 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O segundo parâmetro do método [startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) é um inteiro para identificar esse "request".

[startActivityForResult()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) é usado em conjunto com o método [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) que será chamado após a Activity lançada ser terminada.

Como só se pode ter um [onActivityResult()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) em cada Activity, esse identificador é usado para saber qual foi o `startActivityForResult()` que o chamou.

Altere

```
starActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

para

```
starActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

ou declare a constante `IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST`:

```
protected final static int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
```